# DB2 Privileges for Create or Declare Global / temp table

Tags: db2

Is it possible to grant privileges to allow developers to Create/Declare Temp table/variables but not allow Create Table.

Developers are asked to analyse data from different data sources and a temp table would help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Because of how the feature is supposed to be used, [no special authorization is required](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_declareglobaltemptable.dita):

> ## Authorization
>
> None are required, unless the LIKE clause is specified when additional
>   privileges might be required.
>
> PUBLIC implicitly has the following privileges without GRANT authority
>   for declared temporary tables:
>
> - The CREATETAB privilege to define a declared temporary table in the database that is defined AS WORKFILE, which is the database for declared temporary tables.
> - The USE privilege to use the table spaces in the database that is defined as WORKFILE.
> - All table privileges on the table and authority to drop the table. (Table privileges for a declared temporary table cannot be granted or revoked.)
>
> These implicit privileges are not recorded in the DB2® catalog and
>   cannot be revoked.

The exceptions for the `LIKE` clause basically amount to needing `SELECT` access to the table/columns, which you'd need anyways...

Answer (score 1):

Since temporary tables require a special type of tablespace, *user temporary*, I think you should be able to accomplish this indirectly: issue `GRANT USE OF TABLESPACE` on the user temporary tablespace(s) while revoking that privilege on all regular tablespaces.